# Format Category Labels of Polar Plot (Radar chart)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I exported data as text file from CST Studio in order to plot them in an excel sheet. Everything was fine except that the angles on top of each other. How to display the angles on the plot at an interval of say 30 (i.e. 0 -> 30 -> 60 -> 90 -> .... -> 330)? I tried converting the chart into a line and then adjust the tick and label position to 30, but when I converted it back to a radar chart, I got the same original plot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The outside labels of a radar chart are category labels and will always be text. Formatting options for these labels have always been very limited.

Excel determines automatically how many labels are showing in the available space. In your example it looks like every fourth label is visible.

i.e. 0 - 4 - 8 - 12 - 16 etc.

While you cannot change that algorithm to show every nth label according to your preference, you CAN simply clear some of the source cells so only some of the calculated labels are showing.

In the screenshot, I have highlighted every 4th cell. All the highlighted cells will be showing as category labels. Note how clearing some of the highlighted cells reflects in the chart.

[image]